# Won't generate .apk Android Studio 1.1

Tags: android, android-activity, apk

I have tried to run my app several times and I keep getting this message:

```
Faild to complete Gradle execution,

Cause:
```

I've also started a new project and tried to run that and I'm still getting the same error.

```
Waiting for device.
Target device: Nexus_5_API_21_2 [emulator-5556]
Uploading file
local path:
    C:\Users\Ashley Windows 8\Desktop\Test\app\build\outputs\apk\app-debug.apk
    remote path: /data/local/tmp/app.andriod.ajapps.test

Local path doesn't exist.
```

This has been since a update I believe, my Android Studio isn't generating any .apk files, does anyone know the solution?

Comment: did you clean and rebuild? This should solve the problem

Comment: Yep I've cleaned and rebuilt it and still no joy, I made a new project and ran that without changing any code and i still get the same problem,
I even uninstalled Android Studio and removed the SDK files, then reinstalled Android Studio and re added the SDK's but still getting the same problem.

Comment: If you issue `./gradlew clean assemble` from the command line, does that create the apk files for you?

Comment: when i put "./gradlew clean assemble" in the command line i get ''.' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.'

Comment: Ah, try `gradlew clean assemble`. My bad. Note, do this in the root of your project.

Comment: Its finished and this came up

              
BUILD FAILED  
              
Total time: 3 mins 10.204 secs
              
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
java.lang.NullPointerException (no error message)